# A and B are conditionally independent given C, prove A complement and B complement are conditionally independent given C

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Trying exercise 2.6 in Hoff's Bayesian Statistics book.

Given $A\perp B \space \vert C$

Prove $A^c \perp B^c \space \vert C$

My attempt:

$$
\text{Definition}: A\perp B \space \vert C \iff P(A \cap B \space \vert C) = P(A \vert C)P(B \vert C)
$$
Using the RHS:
$$
RHS = (1-P(A^C \vert C))(1-P(B^C \vert C)) 
$$
$$
RHS = 1 - P(A^c \vert C) - P(B^c \vert C) + P(A^c \vert C)P(B^c \vert C)
$$
Setting LHS to this new RHS:
$$
P(A \cap B \vert C) = 1 - P(A^c \vert C) - P(B^c \vert C) + P(A^c \vert C)P(B^c \vert C)
$$
$$
\implies P(A \cap B \vert C) + P(A^c \vert C) + P(B^c \vert C) - 1 = P(A^c \vert C)P(B^c \vert C)
$$

This is where I am stuck. My RHS is now what I need per the definition. Unsure how to get $P(A^c \cap B^c \vert C)$ on the LHS though.

I tried something like this...

Note:
$$
P(A^c \cap B) = P(A^c \cap B \vert C) + P(A^c \cap B^c \vert C)
$$
$$
P(B^c \cap B) = P(B^c \cap A \vert C) + P(B^c \cap A^c \vert C)
$$
Now, the LHS becomes:
$$
P(A^c \cap B \vert C) + 2P(A^c \cap B^c \vert C) + P(B^c \cap A \vert C) + P(A \cap B \vert C) - 1
$$
Not sure if this is the right way to go though. Would appreciate some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To conclude, note that
$$P(A^c \cap B \mid C) + P(A^c \cap B^c \mid C) + P(B^c \cap A \mid C) + P(A \cap B \mid C) = 1.$$

Comment: I should have figured it would be something as easy as that... Thank you!